# Combining Environments

Tags: environments

I use two (and maybe more in the future) almost identical environments defined as

```
%%% REMARK ENVIROMENT 

\newcounter{remark}[chapter]
\def\theremark{\thesection\cyan{.\arabic{remark}}\blackink}
\newenvironment{remark}[2][]{\refstepcounter{remark}\par\medskip 
\noindent
\mdfsetup{
    frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright }
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=black!10]
\cyan\hrulefill\blackink \\
\colorbox{cyan}{\textbf {\whiteink{\large{REMARK~\theremark}
\rule[-6pt] {0ex}{4ex} }\blackink #1}} 
\smallskip $\quad$ \textbf {#2} \\
\cyan\hrulefill\blackink
}{${}$\\\cyan\hrulefill\blackink\end{mdframed}}

%%% DEFINITION ENVIROMENT 

\newcounter{definition}[section]
\def\thedefinition{\thesection\cyan{.\arabic{definition}}\blackink}
\newenvironment{definition}[2][]{\refstepcounter{definition}\par\medskip  
\noindent
\mdfsetup{
    frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright }
\begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=black!10]
\cyan\hrulefill\blackink \\
\colorbox{cyan}{\textbf {\whiteink{\large{DEFINITION~\thedefinition}   
\rule[-6pt]{0ex}{4ex} }\blackink #1}} \smallskip $\quad$ \textbf {#2} \\
\cyan\hrulefill\blackink
}{${}$\\\cyan\hrulefill\blackink\end{mdframed}}
```

(the only thing that changes is the label of the environment and (maybe) the color). Is it possible to combine them in a single environent (or to use them from another environment) and to select somehow the one i want to use (maybe via an additional parameter?) What if the environments differ in more than one features than their name? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always better to give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) when asking a question, as this normally helps explain what you want -- and it gives people some compliable code to start from.

The code below combines your two environments. Since you said that you might like the change the colour of the environments I have used `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package to define the environments with two optional arguments. For example, you can now write:

```
\begin{definition}(blue!10)[really]{wonderful}
  Here is a really wonderful definition
\end{definition}
```

The first optional argument, which is surrounded by brackets, sets the background colour and the second optional argument is your previous optional argument.

Here is part of the output produced by the MWE code below:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\mdfsetup{
    frametitleaboveskip=-0.5\ht\strutbox,
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright
}
\newcommand\blackink{\color{black}}
\newcommand\whiteink{\color{white}}
\newcommand\cyan{\color{cyan}}

\newcounter{remark}[chapter]
\newcounter{definition}[section]
\renewcommand\theremark{\thesection\cyan{.\arabic{remark}}\blackink}
% usage:
% \begin{MasterEnvironment}{remark/definition}{bg colour}{optional}{rmk/def}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MasterEnvironment}{ m m m m }{%
  \refstepcounter{#1}\par\medskip
  \noindent
  \begin{mdframed}[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=#2]
 \cyan\hrulefill\blackink \\
  \colorbox{cyan}{\textbf{\whiteink{\large{\uppercase{#1}~\csuse{the#1}}
  \rule[-6pt] {0ex}{4ex} }\blackink #3}}
  \smallskip $\quad$ \textbf {#4} \\
  \cyan\hrulefill\blackink
}{${}$\\\cyan\hrulefill\blackink\end{mdframed}}

%%% REMARK ENVIROMENT
% usage: \begin{remark}(bg colour)[optional]{remark}...\end{remark}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{remark}{ D(){black!10} O{} m }%
  {\begin{MasterEnvironment}{remark}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
  {\end{MasterEnvironment}}

%%% DEFINITION ENVIROMENT
% usage: \begin{definition}(bg colour)[optional]{definition}...\end{definition}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{definition}{ D(){black!10} O{} m }%
  {\begin{MasterEnvironment}{definition}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
  {\end{MasterEnvironment}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A walk in the woods}
\section{A nice section}
\begin{definition}{wonderful}
  Here is a wonderful definition
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}[really]{wonderful}
  Here is a really wonderful definition
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}(blue!10){wonderful}
  Here is a wonderful definition
\end{definition}

\begin{remark}{wonderful}
  Here is a wonderful remark
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}[really]{wonderful}
  Here is a really wonderful remark
\end{remark}

\begin{remark}(blue!10){wonderful}
  Here is a wonderful remark
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

A few remarks:

- The `definition` and `remark` environment both have two optional arguments and they pass everything that they are given to the `MasterEnvironment`, which has four mandatory arguments.
- The first argument to `MasterEnvironment` sets both the name and counter to be used: that is, either `definition` or `remark`. Later `\uppercase` is used to put the name in all-caps.
- I have used `\csuse` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to print the counters as `\csuse{the#1}`. You could instead use `\csname the#1\endcsname` here, but I think that `\csuse` makes the code easier to read.
- The definition of `\theremark` as `\thesection\cyan{.\arabic{remark}}\blackink` is a little strange on two counts. First, the `remark` counter is defined as `\newcounter{remark}[chapter]` so it is incremented in step with the `chapter` counter but `\theremark` uses the section counter instead. Secondly, the `remark` number is printed in `cyan` BUT when `\theremark` is used inside the `definition` environment it is printed inside a `\colorbox` with a `cyan` background, which means that you cannot see the `\arabic{remark}`. As it was written like this in the OP I left it like this because this might actually be what is wanted...but, perhaps not.
- As `\blackink`, `\whiteink` and `\cyan` were not defined in the code posted with the question I have defined rough approximations.
- I have moved the `\mdfsetup{...}` outside of the environment definition. Apart from this I have not changed the `mdframed` environment as I assume that this functions as expected